# How to make sure that Xcode 8 doesn't add padding to PNGs it generates from PDF image asset?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, pdf, png

I have been using PDF images for image assets in iOS apps for about a year now. It worked very well in Xcode 7 but it looks like Xcode 8 has broken it.

Here is what I am facing:

This is what my image looks like in image assets:
[image]

When I look in the app bundle to see the PNG images it generated, this is what I get:

[image]

As is visible above, for @2x and @3x images, the canvas size is correct but the actual glyph is the same size as @1x image. This is causing the image to be rendered half the expected size on retina screens.

Anyone else facing this issue?

Comment: Once you are sure you have found a bug in Xcode/iOS you should report it to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com